# How to do this discrete mathematics problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm working on this one for a homework assignment and I just can't come up with the solution:

"Let $d$ be a positive integer and consider any set $A$ of $d+1$ positive integers.  Show that there exists two different numbers $x, y \in A$ so that $x \mod d \cong y \mod d$ and $x \neq y$."

I scanned through the forums but didn't see anything on this. Forgive me if I missed something.

It's probably painfully simple, I just can't think of it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since it's a set of d+1 positive integers it contains all different numbers. Now, apply pigeon hole principle.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There are only $d$ unique residues when considered $\mod{d}$.  But, we have $d+1$ elements in the set.  Thus... (pigeonhole time!)